# glibc and system calls interrupted by signals

Tags: linux, unix, signals, glibc

I'm new to Linux and I'm learning about system calls and signals. For example the `read` system call can be interrupted by a signal. If it's interrupted before anything was read it fails and sets `errno` to `EINTR`. In `glibc` this is mostly handled by the `TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY` macro. But if it's interrupted when only some data was read the functions succeeds reading less than was requested. In this case the caller should issue another `read` for the missing portion, continuing this until all the data is read. Nevertheless the `glibc` source contains numerous calls like this:

```
if (TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY (read (fd, &word, 4)) != 4)
    error (EXIT_FAILURE, errno, _("cannot read header"));
```

This would seem to mean it's, in numerous locations, not restarting the system call properly. Am I missing something? To me it would seem that the partial-read interruption case would be more common than the none-read-yet scenario, and increasingly so as the amount to read requested gets larger.

Answer (score 2):

> But if it's interrupted when only some data was read the functions succeeds reading less than was requested.

Your understanding of this subject is incomplete. You'll want to carefully read this [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) (the "Interruption of system calls and library functions by signal handlers" section of it).

In particular note the distinction between "slow" devices and local disk (which is assumed to be fast).

> This would seem to mean it's, in numerous locations, not restarting the system call properly.

If the read was from a "fast" device and `SA_RESTART` was used, then the system call will have been restarted automatically, and no partial reads are possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, That does shed some light on issue. I definitely have to research it more. Coming from a Windows development background I have to admit to finding *nix's signal/system-call mechanisms (and the interaction between the two) perplexing.